# how to/best practise - conditional validating with IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

my problem is, how can i change the validation rules AND the refresh of them within the runtime. for example(really *just* an example): we have a combo box **vehicle** with the content

- car
- plain
- boat

and a combo box **wheel count**

- 2
- 3
- 4

for the user is it necessary to choose a value in both combo boxes BUT of course not if he choose plain or boat. of course it is not a problem to check
the setting in the validation of the combo box **wheel count**, but when i change the setting in the combo box **vehicle**, then is there no change of the validation result of the combo box **wheel count**.
is it also possible, that the using of IDataErrorInfo not the the best way is. (((

i hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Instead of having 2 unrelated sources of data and validate them it is much better to make second combox to contain only valid data. This prevents user from making mistake, instead of letting him choose 4 wheels for a boat. Think about it as master-details relation.

Comment: You write code that does this.  There is no "best practices" zombie herd for this.  Prototype it and come back if you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the second control while plain or boat is selected. That way the user won't manage to make wrong inputs. Alternatively selectively hide the data.